# Why do all of the ATM cards have the same PIN?

Tags: plot-explanation, t2-trainspotting

In *[T2 Trainspotting](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2763304/)*, Mark and Simon went into a bar and stole ATM Cards from the people there, then went outside and stole the money from their bank accounts by entering 1690 as the PIN for all of the ATM cards as seen below:

[image: Film still showing PIN 1690 overlaid on ATM dispensing cash]

**Why is the PIN the same on all of the ATM cards?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because that was the year of [Battle of the Boyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Boyne).

From the review of [theconversation.com](http://theconversation.com/trainspotting-sequel-is-more-about-losing-life-than-choosing-it-71962)

> Renton and Sick Boy hit upon the larcenous masterstroke of stealing wallets from a Loyalist social club. It turns out militant protestants’ obsession with British sectarian history means they all use “1690” (the year of the Battle of the Boyne) as the PIN code on their bank cards. Conclusion? One can always try to live in the past, but eventually you pay the price.

Comment: Note that also that it is not "all the cards"; they discard a lot of them in the process. It is equivalent to researching your son's name to see if you use as your computer password, with the advantage that no research is required at all because you already know that a fair proportion of cards will have the 1690 PIN.

Comment: Which may be quite strange for someone not knowing you can change your pin. And i have to admint a few weeks ago i wouldn't knew that